# JQuery - Access function from within plugin?

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to call a function from within a jquery plugin.

The example code is:

```
$("#table-2").tableDnD({
    onDragClass: "myDragClass",

    onDrop: function(table, row) {
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        var debugStr = "Row dropped was "+row.id+". New order: ";
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            debugStr += rows[i].id+" ";
        }
        $(#debugArea).html(debugStr);
    },

    onDragStart: function(table, row) {
        $(#debugArea).html("Started dragging row "+row.id);
    }
});
```

The definition of onDrop taken from `http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/` is

**onDrop**

Pass a function that will be called when the row is dropped. The function takes 2 parameters: the table and the row that was dropped. You can work out the new order of the rows by using
table.tBodies[0].rows.

Is it possible to pass a function to this ?
eg :

```
onDrop: doWork(table, row),
```

Where doWork is:

```
function doWork (table, row) {
  var row_id = $(row).prop('id');
}
```

The error is get is:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined(…)` which relates to the line I added for doDrop.

Anyone know anyway to do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
onDrop: doWork(table, row),
```

You are **calling** the function `doWork` with those parameters. As `table` doesn't exists it throws the error.

The correct way to do what you are trying is

```
onDrop: doWork,
```

This way you are setting the function you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
        doWork(table, row)
    }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.